# Flurry Analytics crashes application after second start

Tags: objective-c, flurry

we use flurry (advertisement and analytics) in our application. Since some time the application simple crashes after it was used on this phone and we start it again.

The complete error log:

```
Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_123_4.3.2] 
2014-04-29 12:48:24.875 <ProjectName> 2.0[62373:1303] -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a8068
2014-04-29 12:48:24.879 <ProjectName> 2.0[62373:1303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a8068'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0045c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e748e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x004f9243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0044c50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0044c0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   <ProjectName> 2.0                          0x00128722 +[FlurryProtocolData limitStringLength:] + 35
    6   <ProjectName> 2.0                          0x001289ae +[FlurryProtocolData appendString:toData:] + 46
    7   <ProjectName> 2.0                          0x0012d1f2 -[FlurrySession data] + 1398
    8   <ProjectName> 2.0                          0x0012c3a7 +[FlurrySession addToSavedSessions:] + 148
    9   <ProjectName> 2.0                          0x00128e65 +[FlurrySession sessionWithApiKey:startTime:] + 472
    10  <ProjectName> 2.0                          0x00139fc4 __29-[FlurryImpl setupForApiKey:]_block_invoke + 291
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a1d7b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a324d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a20047 _dispatch_queue_drain + 452
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a1fe42 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a20de2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 78
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03a21127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03d61dab _pthread_wqthread + 336
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03d65cce start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

(username, project name and other privacy related parts have been replaced)

My code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    ...
    [Flurry startSession:@"<API-CODE>"];
    ...


    return YES;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I checked that the variable with the API-Key is really set and removed it even with a fixed value and I still get the same problem. Commenting the line of Flurry fixes the crash.

**Edit 2:**

The problem only appears after I already tracked some events with Flurry. So if I kill the application then and restart it, I get this error message. If I uninstall the application and reinstall it later, the error has gone. So it seems to be something within the saved state of Flurry.

Comment: It is due to some null string..Have you debug the code?? Debugging code give you exact reason

Comment: I debugged it, and the Api-Code is definitive set to the correct value. As soon as I comment the line `[Flurry startSession:@"<API-CODE>"];` everything works again. Do you have some other ideas?

Comment: It actually was because I transmitted an integer as user-id to flurry. But they only support strings for that. So please change your parameters accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually was because I transmitted an integer as user-id to flurry. But they only support strings for that. So please change your parameters accordingly.